# What's wrong with my IF formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am wondering what is wrong with my formula

```
=IF(OR(AND(D2:D="New booking";R2:R != "Partner")AND(D2:D="Google Ad";AA2:AA="Yes"; R2:R != "Partner"))"Default"; S2:S)
```

I want it like this

IF D = New booking & R != Partner then put Default
OR
IF D = Google Ad & Conversion = Yes & R != Partner then put Default
ELSE
Put S2:S (This is all other partners)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you should use arrayformula if you want this formula to work on whole columns. Second - if your goal is to use single formula for whole coulmn you should be aware that AND, OR formulas don't cooperate well with arrayformula.

!= does not work in Google Sheets. Use <>

; as a separator in formulas works only in some countries. Most countries use ,

**WORKING AROUND OR AND with arrayformula**

You can use logical values instead. Like (D2:D="New booking")*(R2:R <> "Partner") makes the same work as and(logical test1 ; logical test2). You multiply conditions. When condition is true it gives 1. When condition is false it gives 0. 0*1 , 1*0, 0*0 gives zero.

You can work around or function using (logical test 1)+(logical test 2) and check value. If it is 1 or more you get the same results as using OR formula.